# How to convert android studio app project into an android library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, gradlew

I want to convert existing android studio app project into an android library and add it as a dependency to new android studio app project.

android studio app project has three android library projects as dependencies along with firebase and Crashlytics integration,

[image]

Now i want to convert this entire project into one android library and add it to another android studio app project.

i have tried changing below lines

```
//from
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//to
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

android library contains google-services.json, and other API keys. so when i add android library as a dependency to new app project, it is only taking modules from android library not google-services.json and other settings

How to solve this issue, Or there is a another process to convert app project to library

Comment: Can you show us what errors you're getting? You may need to shift some dependencies over to your new app project.

Comment: the new app project would be for a third party, android library contains google-services.json, and other API keys. so when i add android library as a dependency to third party app project, it is only taking modules from android library not  google-services.json and other settings

Comment: Firebase is supported only for the application module and is not available for the library modules. So, every project will only contain one `google-services.json` file and its doesn't belong to the library.

Comment: any solution to handle this case, how to convert entire android studio app project to android library.

Comment: 1. Ask the company that wants to integrate the library to create a Firebase Project and add the `google-services.json` file to their project so that they can use your library.
2. Remove the Firebase from the library and find alternates for the features you are relying on Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can init Firebase with values in your google-service.json in your code side. So that you can get rid of google-service.json file.